# ¿Cómo puedo montar un servidor java?

Tags: java, linux, apache, jsp

Hola  amigos disculpen tengo una aplicación **JSP** desarrolla en **Netbeans** y me funciona correctamente en netbeans en el localhost:8080 pero me gustaría saber cómo puedo crear un servidor con soporte java JSP.

Nota : Actualmente tengo un servidor web **Apache** pero para **PHP**, **MySql** y no sé si se pueda configurar Apache vr2 para soportar **Java**, no lo he intentado, porque el servidor está en producción.

Comment: Gracias pero disculpe tom cat no  va  interferir con mis otra  aplicaciones creadas con php?

Comment: Puedes configurarlo para que corra en un puerto diferente y no afecte las demás. Checa mi respuesta ahí te deje mas detalles.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas un servidor de aplicaciones. Dependiendo de que componentes tenga en tu aplicación puede que necesites uno u otro servidor de aplicaciones. Si tu aplicación solo tiene servlets y jsp's, [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) te debiera bastar. Si no lo has configurado antes, puede ser algo confuso hacerlo andar y te encontrarás con varios problemas de variables de ambientes. Te recomiendo que veas como funciona tomcat y que lo hagas funcionar "solo".
En caso de que tu aplicación java, tenga otros componentes (como por ejemplo EJB's), ahi necesitaras otro servidor de aplicaciones, como [JBOSS](http://www.jboss.org) o [Weblogic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/index.html). Tienes que tener en cuenta acá, que el primero es gratuito de usar (pagas el soporte) y para el segundo, tienes que pagar licencia (aunque para desarrollo lo puedes descargar gratuitamente).

Evalúa que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un servidor de aplicaciones tipo Tomcat para desplegar aplicaciones java. Con Netbeans crea un proyecto WAR y una vez arrancado Tomcat, lo despliegas en él. La instalación es muy sencilla http://tomcat.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) en mi caso es nuestro servidor standard para aplicaciones java corporativas, es bastante estable y fácil de configurar ya sea en entornos Windows o Linux.

Te dejo este [manual de configuración](http://blyx.com/public/docs/Apache_Tomcat3.pdf) que incluye la configuración con MySQL.

Obviamente tienes que tener instalada la version de [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html) que uses en tu aplicación.

Si quieres que tus aplicaciones funcionen en paralelo en el mismo server tienes que configurar tomcat para que arranque en un puerto diferente, por default corre en el puerto 8080 así que tienes que revisar en que puerto esta corriendo tu server de PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Si es una aplicación simple *Tomcat*, generalmente el puerto por defecto es el `8080`, si utilizas *Apache* con *PHP*, generalmente es el puerto `80`.

Podés tener *Tomcat* y *Apache* en el mismo *server*, pero siempre tienen que tener puertos diferentes.